# Swift NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, swift, listener, nsnotificationcenter, observers

I'm trying to get the UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification to work. I'm new to using the NSNotificationCenter, so I'm having a hard time understanding what's going on exactly.  I have a UITextView in a storyboard, and I've created an IBOutlet for it in my ViewController class and called it textView.

This is my viewDidLoad function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    origin = self.view.frame.origin.y

    if let field = textView{
        field.placeholder = placeholder
        field.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        field.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor

       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyPressed:"), name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: nil);
    }

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}
```

The keyboard notifications work great.  To my understanding, they call a function with the same name as the selector.  Is that correct?  Or is there something more going on here?  I made a function called keyPressed that took an NSNotification as a parameter, but that function never got called whereas when I engage the keyboard, the keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide functions are called.  Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure that the if statement is actually executed? I'd put a println("Working") or something in there, just to be sure.

Comment: I've debugged it and I know it's being executed.  I figured it out though.  I needed to post the notification...

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem you are having? Also, remove your edit of a solution. If you found a solution, then add it as an Answer and accept your answer. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured out a solution.  I needed to post the notification in the textViewDidChange function.  I did that using this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("keyPressed", object: nil)
```

Then I recognized the notification in my viewDidLoad function with this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyPressed:"), name:"keyPressed", object: nil);
```

Then I made this function under my viewDidLoad function:

```
func keyPressed(sender: NSNotification) {

}
```

Comment: or you can do it in deinit. http://natashatherobot.com/ios8-where-to-remove-observer-for-nsnotification-in-swift/

Comment: Generally, you want to put these in viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear. That way you receive the notifications only when you need them.